# Many To Many Relationship JPA with Entity

Tags: jpa, orm, mapping, many-to-many

I have an issue trying to generate multiple relationship in JPA with three Entities.

- Order
- Product
- Modifier

I have an Entity to handle the relationship many to many.

- OrderProducts (order_id and product_id)
  Contains the relationship of one order can have multiple products
- OrderDetails (order_products_id and modifier_id)
  Contains the id of the previous relationship Order-Products and the Id of the modifier which is a set of multiple values that can affect the price of the product.

Not quite sure how to handle this kind of relationship in JPA as I'm new to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a join entity with a composite key. You will need to research it further.

[image]

Your entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ordertable")
@Data
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<OrderProductModifier> products;
   
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Data
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;
  
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "modifier")
@Data
public class Modifier {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private BigDecimal modifier;
}
```

And the entity that ties it all together will need to have the foreign keys for each of the above entities, as you have noted.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orderproductmodifier")
@Data
public class OrderProductModifier {
    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderProductModifierId id;

    @MapsId("orderId")
    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Order order;
    
    @MapsId("productId")
    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Product product;

    @MapsId("modifierId")
    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Modifier modifier;
}
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Embeddable
@Data
public class OrderProductModifierId implements Serializable {
    private Long orderId;
    private Long productId;
    private Long modifierId;
}
```

This is pretty simple to use:

```
private void run() {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UsersDB");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
     
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    
    Product product = new Product();
    product.setUnitPrice(BigDecimal.TEN);
    em.persist(product);

    Modifier modifier = new Modifier();
    modifier.setModifier(new BigDecimal(".90"));
    em.persist(modifier);

    Order order = new Order();
    em.persist(order);

    OrderProductModifier opm = new OrderProductModifier();
    opm.setId(new OrderProductModifierId());
    opm.setOrder(order);
    opm.setProduct(product);
    opm.setModifier(modifier);
    em.persist(opm);
    
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    em.clear();

    Order o = em.createQuery("select o from Order o join fetch o.products where o.id = 1", Order.class).getSingleResult();
    System.out.println("Order for " + o.getProducts());
    System.out.println("Order cost " + o.getProducts().stream().map(p->p.getProduct().getUnitPrice().multiply(p.getModifier().getModifier()).doubleValue()).collect(Collectors.summingDouble(Double::doubleValue)));

}
```

The above query could be better, but that will give you something to work on.